# Strophejs ejabberd getting archived messages, not getting first message

Tags: ejabberd, strophe.js

I am using strophejs for querying archived messages from ejabberd. I am getting the messages but problem is that first message is not in the response.

The code is as follows

```
var iq = $iq({type: 'set', id: $scope.jid})
            .c('query', {xmlns:'urn:xmpp:mam:1'})
            .c('field',{'var':'with'})
            .c('value')
            .t(jid);

            conn.sendIQ(iq, archivemsg, errbak);

var archivemsg = function(iq) {
     console.log(iq);
}
```

What am I missing.?

Comment: sounds weird but in the XEP-0313  namespace to be used is urn:xmpp:mam:2. Try changing to this and see if it works. Refer https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html

Comment: hi , thanks for the reply. I tried changing to urn:xmpp:mam:2 but iam getting the error message "<query xmlns="urn:xmpp:mam:2"><field var="with"><value>mithun@mjdev022</value></field></query><error xmlns="jabber:client" code="503" type="cancel"><service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/><text xml:lang="en" xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas">No module is handling this query</text></error>"